# Linux: Gedit won't run in foreground

Tags: linux, terminal, background, gedit

If I run gedit in the Linux terminal (`$ gedit`) it opens as a background job; which is not what I'm after at the moment.

Other programs (such as emacs) run in the foreground with commands like (`$ emacs`) and only run in the background if I've specified it via something like (`$ emacs &`).

I've tried searching for a solution but almost everything is about the opposite (trying/struggling to get things to run in the background).

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you get from `type gedit` or `which -a gedit`?

Comment: From `type gedit` I get _gedit is hashed (/usr/bin/gedit/)_ and from `which -a gedit` I get _/usr/bin/gedit/_

Comment: Weird, works for me. What version of gedit do you have?

Comment: Yeah, it really doesn't seem like standard behaviour; so I'm quite baffled! It's version 2.28.4

Comment: I tried with 3.14.4.

Comment: I'm starting to think that perhaps it's just a bug. Unfortunately, it's a work PC so I'm unable to update the version. I guess I can switch to emacs, but a bit annoying I can't use gedit for this aha! Cheers for trying to help mind :)

Comment: you tried with $gedit  file ?

Comment: Do you mean tried opening a file in gedit to see if it still behaves the same? If so the yeah, and sadly it still goes straight to the background.

Answer (score 0):

As it works for me: I run `gedit /tmp/file.txt` for the first time and it runs in the foreground. Then I open another terminal tab and run `gedit /tmp/file2.txt` while Gedit **is still open** — the second command instructs running instance of Gedit to open second tab and exits immediately. Gedit is still in the foreground in the first terminal tab.

According to gedit help, it has an option

> -w, --wait     Open files and block process until files are closed

If in the second terminal tab I run `gedit --wait /tmp/file3.txt`, then it opens a new tab in the existing Gedit window but the command **stays in the foreground** until I close that file tab.

Just in case: it was tested under KDE, Ubuntu 16.04, gedit version is 3.18.3